# How can i delete 2 digits in an unsigned int?

Tags: c

So I have a `1.40` number, and I want to delete the `1.`, so I can convert the `40` to a binary number. How can I just delete 2 digits?

Comment: What is a "binary number"? there's a binary digit, or a binary representation, the number is always a number. Are you talking about strings?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only sane way to do what you want is:

```
double x = 1.40;
int i;
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.2f", x);
i = atoi(buf+2);
```

This looks ugly and horribly inefficient, but the problem with other approaches is that 1.40 *does not exist* in binary floating point. Instead, `1.40` evaluates to the nearest existant floating point value, which may be slightly less or slightly greater than 1.40. If it's less, things like `(int)(x*100)` will give you 139 instead of 140.

Using `snprintf` at least ensures that the same semantics that would be used for displaying the value get used in evaluating it.

Of course what you're doing probably doesn't make sense to begin with. Is 1.40 dollars and cents (or similar in other currency)? If so, you should simply be storing an integer number of cents to begin with. Floating point should **never** be used for currency.

Comment: **Binary** floating-point should never be used for currency. Decimal floating-point was standardized so it could be used for all sorts of currency units, from $/€ where normal people care about two decimals and amounts you may have to express range up to the billions, to others where normal people care about tens of thousands and the amounts you may need to express are proportionally larger.

Comment: @Pascal: While you have a good point, I maintain that using floating point, even decimal floats, for currency is a bad idea. You really need fixed point. Even if you're only working with currency values in the billions, chances are pretty good that someone is going to find a way to get rich (at other people's expense) off of the loss of precision when you take the difference of such numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `1.40` is stored as a floating point or double:

```
double x = 1.40;
int hundreths = (int)(x * 100) % 100;
```

Comment: It is stored as an unsigned int.

Comment: @Doug: how are you storing 1.40 as an unsigned int? fixed point?

Comment: That is a very good question. I forgot about that. My function is using an unsigned int as a parameter, and I've been passing 1.40 into that. You're right, I have to fix that.

Comment: @Doug: Turn up the warning level in your compiler, it will then warn you about errors like that.

Comment: @Doug: what compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using gcc on ubuntu 10.10

Comment: @Doug: try adding `-Wall` as a command line option, it should turn on most of the useful warnings. More info on other flags here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to take the input as a floating pointer number, then subtract the integral part and multiply by 100:

```
unsigned int v = (my_double - floor(my_double)) * 100
```

Note: using floor like this ensures the calculation works even if my_double is outside the range `INT_MIN..INT_MAX`.

Another approach is to take the input as a string, skip to the first ., and convert the rest...

```
const char* p = strchr(my_input, '.');
if (p)
{
    unsigned int v = atoi(p + 1);
    // use v...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a C programmer, but I think I didn't make any mistakes:

```
double y = x - floor(x);
while(y - floor(y) != 0.0){
    y *= 10.0;
    // y %= 10.0, which is
    y -= floor(y / 10) * y

    // The current digit is:
    // floor(y)
    // Push it to a character array or whatever you wanna do.
    // The order for 1.45 is: 4 then 5, for 1.40 it's only 4
}
```

Comment: Damn, well, you get the idea. Also, it may not work as expected with numbers like 0.1

Answer (score 0):

I think ur trying to figure out the binary form of any number and for which u actually don`t need to split it.

But if u do need it, here you go ...

```
#include<iostream.h> 
int main()
{
    double i = 2.40;
    unsigned int j;
    float k;
    j = (int) i / 1;
    k =  i - j ; 
    cout << k;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how you can take the time to type "number" and "binary", but not `your` and `you`.  So why do *u* not use `you` consistently, as in *"But if u do need it here you go"*?

Comment: I see a lot of flags on @Thomas 's comment, but he has a point. Using good English is a gesture of politeness and respect. Using poor English is an indication of laziness and a don't care attitude.

Comment: Point noted, thanks for the suggestion :-).... Basically while multitasking at office this happens. Frankly I just loved the comments :)